# android.view.inflateexception binary xml file line #306: error inflating class guideline

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-constraintlayout

Hey guys I am using Android Studio to create a Brain Training Game.

The thing is that while running the app and then pressing on one of the buttons to choose a level. I get this error `android.view.inflateexception binary xml file line #306: error inflating class guideline`.

I am not sure what this error is. The Logcat says that this is the error line: `setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);`.

This is the `activity_game` xml file:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activitygame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.aadilhafesji.rcw1.Game">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/guess"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="Guess:"
        android:textSize="40dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.033"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/showQuestion"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/showAnswer"
        android:layout_width="110dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="= ?"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/one"
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:tag="1"
        android:text="1"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/four"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/guideline" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/two"
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:tag="2"
        android:text="2"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/five"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/one" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/three"
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:tag="3"
        android:text="3"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/six"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/two" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/four"
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:tag="4"
        android:text="4"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/seven"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/guideline" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/five"
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:tag="5"
        android:text="5"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/eight"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/four" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/six"
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:tag="6"
        android:text="6"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/nine"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/five" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/seven"
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:tag="7"
        android:text="7"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/delete"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/guideline" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/eight"
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:tag="8"
        android:text="8"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/zero"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/seven" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/nine"
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:tag="9"
        android:text="9"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/hash"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/eight" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/zero"
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:tag="0"
        android:text="0"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/delete" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/delete"
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="del"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/guideline" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/hash"
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="#"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/zero" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/minus"
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:tag="-"
        android:text="-"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/hash"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/guideline2"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="549dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/timer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text=""
        android:textSize="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/result"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="40dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.333"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/showQuestion"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.14" />

    <Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="16dp" />

    <Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="360dp" />

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/qHint"
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="118dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:checked="false"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textOff="Hint Off"
        android:textOn="Hint On"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/minus"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/guideline2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dHint"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="Hints left:"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/qHint"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/guideline2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/qHint" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/hintNum"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:text=""
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="40dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/dHint"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/dHint"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/dHint" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

It would be great if someone could really help me out.
Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is `android.support.constraint.Guideline` instead

Comment: That didn't work.. It says android.support.constraint.Guideline cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup

Comment: @AadilHafesji Are you referencing the `Guideline` from within the java code?

Comment: `Guideline` is a `View` and not a `ViewGroup` and it seems like some part of your code is casting the `Guideline` to `ViewGroup`

Answer (score 2):

Now you can use AndroidX instead of 'support'

```
androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
```

Comment: You must define the **layout_width and layout_height** of your layout when using Guideline, otherwise you'll get error.